# Setting Image width and height by WPF styles

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles

Is there any way how to set Image size by WPF styles?

I have in my XAML:
`<Image Style="MyImageStyle" Source="{StaticResource MyImage}" />`

And in ResourceDictionary as a style:

```
<Style x:Key="MyImageStyle">
<Setter Property="Width" Value="30" />
```

But it doesn´t work. I get this error: Cannot resolve the Style Property 'Width'. Verify that the owning type is the Style's TargetType, or use Class.Property syntax to specify the Property.

Thx.

Comment: Might want to read more about [styling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745683.aspx)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Style="{StaticResource MyImageStyle}"
```

([`StaticResource` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189045.aspx) | [class documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.staticresourceextension.aspx))

Answer (score 2):

```
<Style x:Key="myImageStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="30" />
...

<Image Style="{StaticResource MyImageStyle}" Source="{StaticResource MyImage}" />
```